# How to use a for loop to modify multiple controls (gridview)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hello everyone Is it possible to use a for loop to cycle through a set of gridviews and modify each one of them?

Let's say I have 10 gridviews named Gridview1, Gridview2, Gridview3...and so on.

Can i write something like

```
for(int i=1; i<=10;i++)
{
    Gridview[i].Rows[1]...
}
```

Hope I was clear enough, sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `foreach` loop. like this.

```
        foreach (GridView gv in Page.Controls.OfType<GridView>())
        {
           gv.Rows[1].........
        }
```

Other approach, if you are using 2.0 version

```
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
     ((GridView) Page.FindControl("GridView" + i)).Rows[1].........
}
```

[More about foreach](http://www.dotnetperls.com/foreach) and [OfType](http://www.dotnetperls.com/oftype)

Comment: Thanks @jams, I believe this is what I was looking for. But Im getting this error: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView'."

Comment: 'System.Web.UI.Control' does not contain a definition for 'Rows'

Comment: :( 'System.Web.UI.ControlCollection' does not contain a definition for 'OfType' Am I missing a reference maybe?

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;` at top of the page with other namespaces.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17955/discussion-between-jams-and-heinser-diaz)

Comment: yep, thats the problem. Im running 2.0 I think

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop,

```
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
    (Page.FindControl("GridView" + i) as GridView).Rows[1]...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you already store your gridviews in a list like this:

```
List<DataGridView> GridViews = new List<DataGridViews>();

GridViews.Add(myFirstGridView);
GridViews.Add(mySecondGridView);
....
```